# pserve is complaining that __init.py__ "has no 'main' attribute"

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to get a pyramid project running on a new machine, and we've seen this curious error:

```
 pserve pubmanage/production.ini

ImportError: <module 'pubmanage' from '/home/frodeo/pubbery/webapp/pubmanage/__init__.pyc'> has no 'main' attribute
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

pserve is looking for an application entry point and not finding it.

By convention (which is configurable), the `__init__` module of your project contains a `main` function which is fed settings from your .ini file and returns a WSGI application.  Your init seems to lack this entry point.

Read [the Pyramid documentation on startup](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/startup.html) for more details. The step that is failing for you is step 4.

Comment: Thanks. What's interesting is it's working on my development machine but not our target.  I think it's related to the working directory being different, or the module search path.

Comment: Is the file shown in the error message the correct file? If so, it's not a PYTHONCLASS issue. Python found the module but not the `main` function.